# I can't open IDLE Python 2.7 from Terminal

Tags: python, tkinter, macports, python-idle

I’m beginner to coding and I installed python on MacOSX step by step on this site (https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/python/mac/). I installed macports and python perfectly, but when I try to command as    idle2.7 from the terminal it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/opt/local/bin/idle2.7", line 5, in <module>
        main()
   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 1553, in main
        root = Tk(className="Idle")
   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1819, in __init__
        self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
   _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

I can not open it from Applications either. The application opens when I give the idle command on terminal, but it opens in 2.7.10. Can you help me?

Comment: I suggest you change your title to better reflect your actual question.  What is happening is the default behavior.  But if you append a 3 to your title it will make it clear that you want Python 3 instead of 2.7.10.

Comment: `no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable` means that you do not have a running X server. You need to install XQartz (https://www.xquartz.org/) either using their DMG or from MacPorts by installing the `xorg-server` port.

Comment: The problem is with tkinter, not IDLE, which depends on tkinter.  No other tkinter-using program, such as turtle, would work either.

Comment: Have you set your environment variables ?
`PYTHONPATH` and `PATH`

Comment: A duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/878601/what-should-my-display-variable-be-and-why-is-it-not-set